# Interrupts in assembly language with PIC16F877A

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, interrupt

I'm trying to do some Microcontroller practice, I'm kind of a n00b so sorry if this get too obvious.

Basically what we have is a PIC16F877A with to connected buttons to PORTC on RC4 and RC5, configured as inputs. The idea is to use RC5 to activate interrupts and wait for TMR0 interrupt to activate a buzzer (we're using a LED right now). Then, RC4 must deactivate interrupts and stop the buzzer/LED (connected at RC0, counfigured as output).

We made our program and it runs pretty well on MPLAB, but we're having problems to get it to run on the real thing.

This is the program:

```
list p=16f877a
include "p16f877a.inc"
__CONFIG _CP_OFF & _DEBUG_OFF & _WRT_OFF & _CPD_OFF & _LVP_OFF & _BODEN_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _WDT_OFF & _HS_OSC


DELH EQU 0x2C
DELL EQU 0x2F   
DELI EQU 0x2E 
ORG 0x00
GOTO MAIN
ORG 0x04
GOTO INTERRUMPE

MAIN        BCF STATUS,RP0
            BCF STATUS,RP1
            CLRF PORTC
            CLRF PORTB

            BSF STATUS,RP0  
            MOVWF 0xF0
            MOVWF TRISC
            MOVWF 0x00
            MOVWF TRISB
            MOVLW 0x83
            MOVWF OPTION_REG
            BCF STATUS,RP0

TECLA       BTFSS PORTC,5
            GOTO TECLA
            MOVLW  0xB8
            MOVWF INTCON
            MOVLW 0x63
            MOVWF TMR0        


TECLA2      BTFSS PORTC,4
            GOTO TECLA2
            BCF INTCON,7
            BCF PORTC,0
            GOTO TECLA   

INTERRUMPE BTFSS INTCON,2
           GOTO REGRESO
           BSF PORTC,0
           MOVLW 0xBF
           MOVWF TMR0
           BCF  INTCON,T0IF
REGRESO    RETFIE   

END
```

We have to following minimum system:

http://prntscr.com/jkz88

And it didn't do Anything until we changed the oscilator from 4Mhz to 12Mhz, With the 12 Mhz oscilator it kind of worked, but gets a little crazy. We also tried 20Mhz but it didn't work quite well either.
We've even tried different configuration words but we didn't get any good results.

Please help, I'm a bit desperate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code

```
        MOVWF 0xF0
        MOVWF TRISC
        MOVWF 0x00
        MOVWF TRISB
```

does not do what it is  supposed to do, MOVWF moves the content of the working register to the GPR or SFR or its address, so what you are doing is you are filling address 0xF0 (a GPR) and 0x00 (indirect addressing register) with  the unknown value of the working register. Instead, your code should start as

```
        MOVLW 0xF0
        MOVWF TRISC
        MOVLW 0x00
        MOVWF TRISB
```

Also, if RC4 and RC4 inputs are push buttons or switches, consider implementing a de-bouncing solution either in HW or SW

Finally, for the clock settings, if you are using an 8MHz clock or higher, the configuration word in MPLAB should be set to HS, if you are using 4 MHz, then it should be XT.